# SAS proc sql update table with count and max

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sas, proc-sql

I want to create a table on the right side from that on the left side:
[image]

I first used the following codes to create a new table (worked!):

```
proc sql;
    create table (table_right) as
        select distinct Customer format $15.
        from (table_left);
    select * from (table_right);
run;

proc sql;
    alter table (table_right)
        add Count_bin30 num label='Count_bin30' format=1000000.,
            Max_Date_Diff num label='Max_Date_Diff' format=1000000.;
    select Customer format=$15.,
           Count_bin30,
           Max_Date_Diff
    from (table_right);
run;
```

And then I was stuck when I tried to update the newly added columns:

```
proc sql;
    update (table_right)
        set Count_bin30 = select count(Date_bin)
        from (table_left)
        where Date_bin='bin30';
run;

proc sql;
    update (table_right)
        set Max_Date_Diff = select max(Date_diff)
        from (table_left);
run;
```

Any solution is much appreciated!

Comment: It's easier to work with your data if you don't post it as an image.

Comment: Well noted.  Will avoid doing this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the multiple proc sql statements, you can achieve the result in one go.  Also note that `proc sql` is ended with `quit`, not `run`.

```
data table_left;
input customer $ date_diff date_bin $;
datalines;
James 0 0 
James 35 bin30
James 0 0
James 30 bin30
James 0 0
James 0 0
Daniel 0 0
Daniel 45 bin30
Daniel 61 bin60
Daniel 0 0
Ivy 0 0
Ivy 0 0
Ivy 0 0
Ivy 0 0
Ivy 108 bin90
Laura 0 0
Laura 0 0
;
run;

proc sql;
create table table_right
as select
customer,
sum(case when date_bin='bin30' then 1 else 0 end) as Count_bin30,
max(date_diff) as Max_Date_Diff
from table_left
group by customer
;
quit;
```

Comment: Wow this not only solves my problem but is very neat... great thanks!